# Image object in javascript does not return width and height

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, caching

I am writing a javascript code for image carousel where visitors can click through the images.

For some reason, image object returns 0 for width, height, naturalWdith, or naturalHeight. Also, the variable (nextImg) referenced to image object changes between  DOM and image object each time I reload the browser.

The issue is in loadImg function, which is the last function in the code. I included other portions of code for context.

```
var imgArray = document.querySelectorAll("#container img");
var current = 0; //index for imgArray

var nextImg = new Image();

var imgName;

function moveToNextImg(){
    //increment index to access next image in the array
    if(current === imgArray.length-1){
        current = 0;
    }
    else{
        current++;
    }
    updateIndex();

    //Fade out current image and execute loadImg after animation. 
    $("#imgWrapper").fadeOut("slow",loadImg);
 }

function loadImg(){

//imgArray contains <img> DOM, which are thumbnail images.  
    imgName = imgArray[current].getAttribute("src");

//Hi-res file names need "_Thumb" removed from from the thumbnail image file names. 
    nextImg.src = imgName.replace("_Thumb","");

    h = imgArray[current].naturalHeight;
    w = nextImg.naturalWidth; // returns 0, WHY?

    nextImg.id = "currentImg";

//Find out if the image if portrait or landscape orientation. Compare image height and width.   
    if((nextImg.height) > (nextImg.width)){
         //nextImg.height and nextImg.width are both 0. WHY??
        // console.log("portrait")
        nextImg.style.width = "32.5%"
    }

    else{
        nextImg.style.width = '750px';  
    }
        //Fadein the image.
        $("#imgWrapper").fadeIn("slow")

    }
```

Comment: You need to wait for the image to be done loading before you can query its dimensions. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+image+load+event